# How to display lyrics as per song playing in android?

Tags: android, textview, android-mediaplayer

I would like to create music player, with a textView displaying lyrics of MP3 being played. The lyrics should displayed in sync with music.

I want to know that **how to get lyrics** and for display the text I refer this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970927/marquee-set-speed).

Any suggestions on how I can do this? I am stuck in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do u got any solution for this ?.i too got struck here

Comment: The Cyanogen eleven music player can play lyrics from `.srt` files: https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/themes-apps/app-music-player-cyanogen-t2974688 — they must have the same file name as the mp3 file and end in `.srt`.

Answer (score 8):

Use the following music metadata library.

> http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/

You can go to documentation and look for Lyrics tag and follow it. 
Normally you would open the mp3 file and extract the vaule of the Lyrics tag. Note that this may or may not be available inside the mp3. (I suggest you use a tagged mp3 for testing) If the info is there. You will be able to extract it as a String or a buffer.

That info will look like this

```
[00:02]Let's talk about time
[00:05]tickin away every day
```

Now you just need to display the line according to the time given at the front of the line. This should be simple enough, just do some string operations.

Comment: is this library for android too?

Answer (score 2):

As [brandall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256219/brandall) wrote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976697/2829009), there is **no native way to convert audio files to text in Android**. However, you could use the libraries he suggests in his answer ([Nuance](http://nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home) and [A&T](http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=12500023) look good to me).

As an alternative, I would **use an API to get the lyrics for the song** such as [chartlyrics.com](http://www.chartlyrics.com/api.aspx).

Now you have the lyrics, but syncing them with the song is very difficult. I don't know how to do it and would display the whole lyrics to let the user scroll through.

Comment: how are then subtitles implemented in Android ?  If we have lrc file then is it possible ?

Comment: @user3726986 Yes, with a .lrc file it is rather easy. It contains the time when you have to switch the text, so you can sync it with the currently playing video/audio.

Answer (score 1):

you can use speechToText for this

Comment: Yes you are write but I am not able to understand that How can I get the text from song is playing.

Comment: refer this http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/

Comment: hey yuva nice tutorial and example but I want to play song and the lyrics of that song I want to display into textview. But I have no idea about how to get lyrics of that playing song.

Comment: for that you can use that code and make some modification,play song.

Comment: Yes that same I thinking.. But How can I get the lyrics of song that I dont know. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to use lyrics as subtitles. If you look at a subtitles file, you will see that it has the following format
time string 
You need a lyrics file to be like that. Read in the lyrics file and then display lyrics on the screen at those specified times.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want to suggest to me. Can you please explain with example? Thanks.