# Speech to Text: Play MP3 message by itself and retrieve words

Tags: java, android, mp3, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I have few MP3 files which are speeches. I have used Android Speech to Text before so I know it can store spoken words. Is there any way where we can get the spoken words from the MP3 and display it in a `EditText` ?

I am thinking about playing the MP3 silently and identify the words, but have no idea about how to do that. I am using Google Speech Engine.

Comment: In case u play video did u got words ? if yes then we can try for silent playing mp3

Comment: @MT8: Hello, Thanks for the reply. No video, audio only. Is that iss what you asked?

Comment: i mean , if u play audio [not silently] can u capture that words ? if yes then i think ur query will be solved

Comment: @MT8: no.............

Comment: ok did u tryed codeing? can u post?

Answer (score 5):

There is no native way to convert an audio file that contains spoken words to text on Android. You'll need to use a third-party API to do this, such as.

1. [A&T](http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=12500023)
2. [Nuance](http://nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home)
3. [iSpeech](http://www.ispeech.org/)

And perhaps [Pocket Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/), although you may have to write the file input stream side of it yourself.

If you're not concerned about breaking terms and conditions, you could use the [Chrome Speech API](https://gist.github.com/alotaiba/1730160).

Comment: Hi,tell me more about this. have you tried this before? By engine to engine, the way we code is different? I don't think so. Interested about Chrome thing. First time I heared,

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence - They all have Android SDKs with example code you can use. I use them all successfully in my application. You can use RESTful methods too if you want. I've updated the post with the Chrome API link

Comment: This API might also be helpful, but you will need to convert (or decode) the audio file. https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api