# how to display lyric while song is playing android?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have some songs and their lyric. now I want to display lyric while song is playing. but i don't how to do this. i read some topic like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939223/how-to-display-lyrics-as-per-song-playing-in-android)

but they are not clear to me. is there any tutorial for that?
I should read a ".lrc" file and search for time stamp how to use them?
I think I can put this time stamp in array and according to this times start a textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good example for you to do this:

https://github.com/douzifly/AndroidLrcView