# Highlight text while playing audio clip in android media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a textview in which I have display the lyrics of one audio song & simultaneously i play the audio from raw folder and now I want to highlight the lyrics from textview as per the audio play. So anyone has any idea about this. I have the source code to highlight I just want to find the word palying in audio.

Comment: this should work for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970927/marquee-set-speed

Comment: You've asked multiple questions like this here. I recommend reading our help center for more information on the kind of questions we expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use spannable
find the word that playing and change the color

```
Spannable WordtoSpan = (Spannable) tvContactName.getText();

WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), keyPos, keyPos +
LyricHighLightedText.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

tvLyric.setText(WordtoSpan);

//LyricHighLightedText means the current word that play on audio
```

Comment: Hi Leon_SFS, I have the highlight text code but I unable to get the single word in string which is playing currently in audio file.. So how to find that "current word that play on audio"

Comment: you want find out current word that play on audio dynamically? if yes. sorry i don't have experience on voice recognition :(

Comment: ok.. so how you find out that "LyricHighLightedText" in your above given code...

Comment: you can act like video subtitle,define lyric text file with timeline that related to audio timeline,read the text file, start timer when audio play and depend on timer time colored the current word from lyric text file

Comment: @Saeed-rz is there any sample app/source that highlights text according to playing audio.

Comment: @Al-Amin https://github.com/adrianblp/Noraoke
maybe helpful

Comment: @Saeed-rz Thanks for your response.