# How to get the speed of the auto scrolling of Android Textview

Tags: android, textview

I want to to know if there is any way to get the speed of the auto scrolling when textview in android is set to have elipsize= "marquee". If not then can anybody tell me what the speed is in exact units??
I do not want to speed up the maruquee scrolling speed. Just need the speed. I know the marquee attribute in textview can be accessed with Field object to get the amount in marquee. But how do you calculate the speed from it??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Marquee Set Speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970927/marquee-set-speed)

Comment: I had looked at the question you said this one to be a duplicate of, before. It did not solve my problem. I want to get the speed of the scrolling. Not the marquee field of the text view. It can be used to customize the speed. But can you tell me how to calculate the speed from it. The marquee attribute gives you different float values corresponding to the different size of texts. TIA

Comment: As a quick solution, you can use HorizontalScrollView and control its scroll keeping text inside it at wrap_content width

Comment: Okay, but I am not really looking to control the scrolling speed. Suppose i wanna make a translation animation with the exact speed of the auto scrolling textview. So to do that I would need to match the animation speed with the textview. How do I do that?