# Smooth scrolling effect from right to left

Tags: java, scroll, smooth-scrolling, scroller

I use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970927/marquee-set-speed/8971920#8971920) snippet to make the text scroll from right to left.
But I want it to have smoother motion, it can move like this??

[image: [enter image description here]()]

I have tried continuously checking the scroll position coordinates to make two TextViews run alternately with each other, but it consumes a lot of resources and the two TextViews overlap during scrolling.