# How to make marquee text without stopping programmatically- Android Java

Tags: java, android, animation, textview, marquee

I would like to ask how to make a marquee text without stopping when reaching the beginning programmaticaly. Currently I have the plain TextView made programmatically as marquee:

```
textview47.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
textview47.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
textview47.setSelected(true);
```

However when the text reaches its beginning, it stops moving for one or two seconds. How do I disable this "stopping feature" programmatically (not by XML)? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at a custom view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8971920/6287910).